# What is the difference between C# , .NET and CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

What is the difference between C# , .NET and CLI?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C# is one of the .NET languages - VB.NET, F# and [many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages) exist.

[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) is a platform (libraries, compiler and runtime) on which code written by any of these languages runs.

[CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) is the Common Language Infrastructure - it is a specification that describes the executable code and runtime that make the .NET platform. Apart from the Microsoft one, there are other implementations - [mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)) and [Portable.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable.NET) the most known.

If you want some more acronyms:

- There is also the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) - the common language runtime, which is the Microsoft implementation of the CLI, mentioned above.
- In addition, on top of the CLR, Microsoft have created the [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime) - the dynamic language runtime is a set of services for several dynamic languages such as python and ruby.

Answer (score 0):

well, c# is programming language,CLR is the tool or framework so you write your code using c#, CLR convert that codes to Microprocessor's language and all order up to your c# code CLR coordinate memory,microprocessor and other sources, so if you work in that situation or you make a product with this, they say your done your job up to .NET